# SQL Server : group by column with another column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

From a table like below, I want to get itemName and emails where the same itemName has been emailed to different email addresses. Same email can receive different itemNames. Same itemname can appear in multiple places in the table, they are not always ordered by id. ItemNames are unique as in it's fine to self join by itemname.

**I tried :**

I tried a bunch of queries with row_number, group by , having etc. but can't get it right.

Is anyone able to help?

**Sample data:**

```
declare @t table (id int, itemname nvarchar(50), emailto nvarchar(50))

insert into @t 
values (1, 'item1', 'email1') --include 1 & 2 because same item went to different emails
       , (2, 'item1', 'email2') 
       , (3, 'item2', 'email1') --exclude because even though email1   received an email before, item2 went to a sinle email 
       , (4, 'item3', 'email3') --exclude 4, 5, 6 becuase all item3 went to the same email
       , (5, 'item3', 'email3')
       , (6, 'item3', 'email3')
       , (7, 'item4', 'email6')
       , (8, 'item4', 'email6') --include 8 & 9, only reason to exclude 7 is to get a distinct list of itemName and email pairs
       , (9, 'item4', 'email7')
       , (10, 'item3', 'email3') --exclude 10 becuase all item3 went to the same email, this is the same item from 4, 5, 6

;with expectedOutput as 
(
    select 
        t.itemname, t.emailto
    from @t t
    where 
       t.id IN (1, 2, 8, 9)
)
select *
from expectedOutput

/*
Expected output:
itemname    emailto
item1       email1
item1       email2
item4       email6
item4       email7

*/
```

Comment: plus 1 for sample data, going forward please post expected output as well

Comment: Mr curious now I am curious why software devs call SQL Server just as mssql even when you know the proper name based on the tag you used? :)

Comment: @TheGameiswar expected results is also in sql script here...

Comment: @ZoharPeled:my intention was to ask the user to post the total expected output.I thought it would be better

Comment: @TheGameiswar I also though it's not very clear like it was posted, but then again it was very helpful when I copied the code to rextester and could immediately see the expected output vs my own query output. Still, I think you are correct and desired output should be present in the question as a table as well.

Comment: @BartoszX Not sure really but I think it's got something to do with being .Net developer means you're always using microsoft products like .Net and linq and EF etc. and all that, so it's embedded in my brain that everything I use is a MS product? Maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to do it - Use a CTE to get all the items that was sent to more than one email, and then join that cte with the original table:

```
;WITH Items AS
(
    SELECT itemname
    FROM @t
    GROUP BY itemname
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT emailto) > 1
)

SELECT DISTINCT t.itemname, emailto
FROM @t t
INNER JOIN Items i ON t.itemname = i.itemname
```

Result:

```
itemname    emailto
item1       email1
item1       email2
item4       email6
item4       email7
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming what you are looking for are unique pairs of email and item.

```
with expectedOutput as 
(select distinct 
  t.itemname,
  t.emailto
from @t t),
steptwo as (
    select tt.itemname, count(distinct tt.emailto) as nemails
    from expectedOutput tt
    group by tt.itemname
)
select tw.itemname,e.emailto from steptwo tw join expectedOutput e 
on tw.itemname = e.itemname 
WHERE nemails > 1
```

yielding

```
item1   email1
item1   email2
item4   email6
item4   email7
```

We've all been there.

Comment: It shouldn't have `item2 - email1` pair because item2 went to a single email.

Comment: Upvoted as it works but the other answer is a better solution. Thanks.